# Get Error When Use T4MVC And RazorGenerator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc, razorgenerator

When I use T4MVC And RazorGenerator I get these errors :

[image]

Comment: Right click on T4MVC.tt file and click on 'run custom tool' option. i think it may work for you

Comment: @peter Thanks Fixed